# How to add Bottom Navigation and Tab Navigation both at the same time in React Native using React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, debugging, native, react-native-navigation

I am currently developing an application using React Native. I wanted to add Bottom Navigation and Tab Navigation. However, came across this bug. [image: iPhone Simulator Screenshot]

As seen in the screenshot the top section is the Tab Navigation and the bottom section is the bottom navigation. Some how they got separated.

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import React from 'react';
import AroundYou from './Screens/AroundYou';
import HighlyRated from './Screens/HighlyRated';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TopNavigation = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false, tabBarAllowFontScaling: false, tabBarStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#181A20"
      }
    }} >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={AroundYou}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <TopNavigation.Navigator>
          <TopNavigation.Screen name="AroundYou" component={AroundYou} />
          <TopNavigation.Screen name="HighlyRated" component={HighlyRated} />
        </TopNavigation.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tabs />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

this is the code for the Top Tab Navigation as well as the bottom navigation. I am kind of know what it causing this bug but not sure on how to get around it.

Thank you